# Please remember to answer the question

Tags: discussion, answers

There appears to be a growing trend for someone to ask a question and for people to write related information to that question without explicitly answering the question

Remember TGO and all SE sites are not forums they are Q&A sites. So please make sure you answer the OPs question.

---

Just to highlight an example, in [this question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/is-camping-at-zion-national-park-in-mid-december-feasible) the OP asks:

> - How cold (in terms of real feel -- sometimes past average temperature    range is not sufficient as a reference for this sort of
>     planning) it    would be? Is camping really a good idea for that time?
> - What additional items should I prepare or be prepared for compared to    times at milder temperature?

The first <strike>answer</strike> (now converted to a comment) on this question (not wanting to single anyone out) simply does not answer the questions being asked. It expresses another concern, not asked about by OP. Does the OP want this info, maybe, has he asked for it, no. Do either of the questions getting asked get addressed in this answer, no.

Comment: This question is a good example (imho): http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/possible-to-transform-at-least-two-smartphones-into-walkie-talkie-like-devices